# Makefile variable and loop

Tags: foreach, makefile

I've got some makefile generated by conan which is included by my main Makefile. That generated Makefile (conanbuildinfo.mak) contains some variable lets say it is something like this:

`CONAN_LIBS = librarya libraryb libraryc`

Starting with this in my main makefile:

`LIBS=-lsocket`

I'd like to achieve following end result:

`LIBS=-lsocket -llibrarya -llibraryb -llibraryc`

so iterate over $CONAN_LIBS and add each variable with -l prefix to LIBS.

How can I do it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make you can try 'foreach':

```
CONAN_LIBS = librarya libraryb libraryc
LIBS = $(foreach entry, $(CONAN_LIBS), -l$(entry))
all:
    echo $(LIBS)
```

> make all

```
-llibrarya -llibraryb -llibraryc
```

Comment: ```CONAN_LIBS = librarya libraryb libraryc
LIBS = -lsocket
LIBS += $(foreach entry, $(CONAN_LIBS), -l$(entry))
all:
        echo $(LIBS)```
is what I was looking for. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You can also use `addprefix` which might be a bit simpler to read: `$(addprefix -l,$(LIBS))`